# How to grep/count distinct values from multiple files

Tags: regex, command-line, grep

I have multiple files that have key/values

file#1:

```
key1: 1
key2: 2
key3: 3
key4: 4
```

file#2:

```
key1: 1
key2: 23
key3: 23
key4: 4
```

file#3:

```
key1: 20
key2: 223
key3: 213
key4: 0
```

How can I find out if each key has a distinct value in all the files? And how to grep and count all distinct values from all files?

```
Expected outputs:
key name : count
key1: 2
key2: 3
key3: 3
key4: 2
```

Comment: For example, I want to know key1 has two distinct values(1 and 20) and also want to know for the value 1, how many files share this value (in this example, it's 2 since file 1 and file 2 share the same value) while file#3 has a different value 20

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat file{1,2,3} | sort -k1,1 -k2n | uniq -c

      2 key1: 1
      1 key1: 20
      1 key2: 2
      1 key2: 23
      1 key2: 223
      1 key3: 3
      1 key3: 23
      1 key3: 213
      1 key4: 0
      2 key4: 4
```

will give you that `key: 1` appears twice and `key1: 20` exists too.
pipe to

```
... | awk '$1>1'

  2 key1: 1
  2 key4: 4
```

gives you that two keys have duplicated values.  Or all in `awk`

```
$ awk '{a[$0]++} 
    END{for(k in a) if(a[k]>1) print a[k], k}' file{1,2,3}

2 key1: 1
2 key4: 4
```

you can specify input in any way bash can expand to list of files, for example `dir/*.txt` will do.

Well, the question changed!  Now, this is what you want

```
$ cat file{1,2,3} | sort -k1,1 -k2n | uniq -c | 
  awk '{print $2}'| uniq -c | 
  awk 'BEGIN{print "keyword","count"} {print $2,$1}'

keyword count
key1: 2
key2: 3
key3: 3
key4: 2
```

or, all in a single `awk`

```
$ awk '{a[$0]++} 
    END{print "keyname", "count"; 
        for(k in a) {split(k,b," ") c[b[1]]++} 
        for(k in c) {print k, c[k]}}' file{1,2,3}

keyname count
key3: 3
key4: 2
key1: 2
key2: 3
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to not explicitly include the file names but the directory instead?

Comment: Thank you very much!! Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

```
for key in `awk -F ":" '{print $1 }' file1`;do grep key <file1> <file2> <file3> |sort -n | uniq|wc -l;done
```

if you want to sum up all distict values

```
for key in `awk -F ":" '{print $1 }' file1`;do grep key <file1> <file2> <file3> |awk -F ":" '{sum+=$2}END{print sum}';done
```